# need to remove multiple "-" from the string which is alpha numeric using tcl

Tags: tcl, itcl

I have this string:

```
svpts-7-40.0001
```

And I need to remove the second '-' from this. 
Basically I am fetching values like these which would come with double '-' SOMETIMES. So if such variables are seen then I have to remove the second '-' and replace the same with '.' , so the string should look like:

```
svpts-7.40.0001
```

---

[EDIT] I have tried:

```
% set list1 [split $string -]
svpts 7 40.0001
% set var2 [join $list1 .]
svpts.7.40.0001
%
```

Comment: tried split and join:

    % set list1 [split $string -]
    svpts 7 40.0001
    % set var2 [join $list1 .]
    svpts.7.40.0001
    %

but joins on basis of . for all items it has to happen only for second hyphen(-) @Jolta

Comment: 'need to remove multiple "-"' -- does that mean if there can be instances where you need to remove more than one of the hyphens?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regular expression that will change only the 2nd hyphen:

```
% regsub -expanded {( .*? - .*? ) -} "svpts-7-40.0001" {\1.}
svpts-7.40.0001

% regsub -expanded {( .*? - .*? ) -} "svpts-7_40.0001" {\1.}
svpts-7_40.0001

% regsub -expanded {( .*? - .*? ) -} "svpts-7-40.0001-a-b-c" {\1.}
svpts-7.40.0001-a-b-c
```

Comment: that helped and most optimal, costly operation but still gets pefect output thanks glenn

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
% set data svpts-7-40.0001
svpts-7-40.0001
% regexp {([^-]*-)(.*)} $data -> a b
1
% set b [string map {- .} $b]
7.40.0001
% set newdata $a$b
svpts-7.40.0001
```

The above code changes every hyphen after the first. To change only the second hyphen, one can do this:

```
set idx [string first - $data [string first - $data]+1]
set newdata [string replace $data $idx $idx .]
```

or this:

```
set idxs [lindex [regexp -inline -all -indices -- - $data] 1]
set newdata [string replace $data {*}$idxs .]
```

The first snippet is well-behaved if the data string doesn't contain at least two hyphens; the other needs some kind of checking to avoid throwing an error.

Documentation:
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl index expressions:*

- *integer* zero-based index number
- `end` the last element
- `end`*-N* the *n*th element before the last element
- `end`*+N* the *n*th element after the last element (in practice, *N* should be negative)
- *M-N* the *n*th element before element *m*
- *M+N* the *n*th element after element *m*

There can be no whitespace within the expression.